# how to use MongoDB $cond in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to conditionally update a field in MongoDB, the expected result is newdata if not exist, but the result I got is `data = {$cond:[exist", "data", newdata]}`

Here is my code:

```
update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"data": bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{"exist", "data", newdata}}}}
collection.UpdateByID(id, update)
```

Any one can help me take a look?

Comment: Here is an example. The native code: `{ $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$fld_1", 0 ] }, { fld_2: "true_value" }, { fld_2: "false_value" } ] }`, can be written as: `bson.D{{ "$cond",  bson.A{ bson.D{{ "$eq",  bson.A{ "$fld_1", 0 }}}, bson.D{{ "fld_2", "true_value" }}, bson.D{{ "fld_2", "false_value" }}}}}` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change data when exists then you can use `$ifNull` aggrigation:

```golang
update := bson.A{bson.M{$set:bson.M{"data":bson.M{"$ifNull":bson.A{"$data",newdata}}}}}
```

Otherwise if you want to set data in any case; there seems to be no way to do this in one update right now.
So you must do it in two separate updates with two inverted filters like these:

```golang
//first filter
 bson.M{"data":{"$exists":true}}
//second filter
 bson.M{"data":{"$exists":false}}
```

*Note that use `bson.A` to implement arrays (Known by brackets `[]`)*